# Use grep to find strings at the beginning of a line or after a delimiter in Git Bash for Windows

Tags: regex, grep, git-bash

I have such file:

```
blue|1|red|2
green|3|blue|4
darkblue|0|yellow|3
```

I want to use grep to find anything containg `blue|` at the beginning of line or `|blue|` anywhere, but not any `darkblue|` or `|darkblue|` or `|blueberry|`

I tried to use `grep [^|\|]blue\|` but Git Bash gives me error:

```
$ grep [^|\|]blue\| *.*
grep: Unmatched [ or [^
sh.exe": |]blue|: command not found
```

What did I do wrong? What's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick & dirty one:

```
grep -E '(^|\|)blue\|' *
```

Matches start of line or `|`, followed by `blue|`.  The important note is that you need extended regular expressions (via `egrep` or the `-E` flag) to use the `|` (or) construct.

Answer (score 1):

Also, note the single quotes around the regular expression.

So, in answer to the OP's "What did I do wrong?",

1. You forgot to put the regexp in single quotes;
2. You chose the wrong type of brackets to enclose the alternate expressions; and finally
3. You forgot to use egrep or the -E flag

It's always easier to see other people's errors; I wish I was a quick to spot my own :-|